# "In Thursday's ruling" Could you simplify it?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm having trouble understanding what "in Thursday's ruling" means here. Here is the extract:

> Sollecito was given 25 years and US ex-girlfriend Amanda Knox 28 years and six months in Thursday's ruling.

Can you simplify it, without shortening it?

Here is the passage:

> Italian Raffaele Sollecito has been stopped by police near the Austrian border following the reinstatement of his guilty verdict for the murder of Briton Meredith Kercher in 2007. Sollecito was stopped between Udine and Tarvisio, near the Slovenia and Austria borders, Italy's Rai News said.A travel ban was part of the verdict handed down on Sollecito. Sollecito was given 25 years and US ex-girlfriend Amanda Knox 28 years and six months in Thursday's ruling.

Answer (score 2):

A [**ruling**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/ruling_1) is a decision made by a judge. All this passage means is that a judge made a ruling on Thursday. The ruling in this case was two prison terms.

When talking about the specifics of the decision (in other words, what the ruling actually was), the preposition *in* is the one typically used, as was done in this excerpt. However, in other contexts, other prepositions could be used; for example:

> The reporter wanted to know more about the implications **of** the judge's ruling.

Answer (score 1):

> A travel ban was part of the verdict handed down on Sollecito. Sollecito was given 25 years and US ex-girlfriend Amanda Knox 28 years and six months in **Thursday's ruling.**

It's just the ruling happened/declared on some Thursday (probably the last Thursday). The author is probably talking about the travel ban which was a part of the verdict.